Como puedo interactuar con un botón que cambia usando selenium y python?
Tengo el siguiente código, donde lo que hago es cargar un archivo a una web, utilizo selemium para poder interactuar con la pagina a traves de python, ya pude ubicar el botón al inspeccionar la pagina que se encarga de subir el archivo y saque su xpath, sim embargo no me había percatado que al interactuar con esta pagina el xpath cambia unos números, entonces cuando quiero hacer una segunda prueba no interactúa por que no encuentra el elemento, esto debido a que cambio de numero en el botón que sube el archivo, saben como podría referirme al botón sin que este cambie su xpath? dejo mi código y el código de donde estoy sacando el xpath.

mi codigo
import time
import os

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.maximize_window()
browser.implicitly_wait(3)

browser.get('++++++++++++++++++++++.com')

time.sleep(2)

user = '*******'
browser.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="ext-comp-1002"]').send_keys(user)
password = '*************'
browser.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="ext-comp-1003"]').send_keys(password)

browser.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="ext-gen25"]').click() #click para ingresar

browser.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="extdd-51"]').click() #Carpeta

browser.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="ext-gen98"]').click() #Subir archivo

file1 = 'C:\\Users\\soriano.ricardo\\Consolidados\\test1.xlsx' #Ruta del archivo

browser.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="userfile0-file"]').send_keys(file1) #Cargar el archivo de la ruta especificada

browser.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="ext-gen235"]').click() #grabar el archivo, **aquí es donde tengo el problema ya que el xpath cambia de numero en la parte que dice gen235**.


Si la id no te vale trata de buscar algo que sea único en él, la clase,  el texto (algo como "//button[text()='Grabar']" o "//*[contains(text(), 'Grabar')]") ,o la combinación de varias.

O ubicalo por sus ancestros. Por ejemplo, //table/tbody/tr/td/button, no es necesario que uses la ruta completa. Solo que no haya demasiados elementos con ese xpath, en lo posible uno solo.

Muchas gracias, justo estuve investigando un poco sobre los xpath y sus padres, trabaje con la clase que esta 2 líneas de código arriba del botón <td class="x-btn-mc" y me funciono muy bien, además de que no es variable como el botón, les agradezco el apoyo.
